# WP_Query with groupby on meta_key field

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm setting up an event calendar in WordPress and need to list all the events of the week *grouped by the current day*. I have events that last only one day and others that last the entire month.

I created the custom *post_type* "Events" and the custom fields "**`initial_date`**" and "**`end_date`**". How would I get the query that returns the custom post types "`events`" for a day but also the ones that are in progress?

Comment: Just for a single day? A WHERE clause that checks for initial_date <= today && end_date >= today // If you want this for a whole date range in one go, then it might make more sense to select all events that fall into the range, and do the rest in PHP.

Comment: Not only single day but the week. How would be the WP_Query from this query?

Comment: You have to do this with custom MySQL query because WP_Query doesn't have any groupby option. If MySQL will do then I can help you other wise CBroe has good suggestion.